# Rel attribute in JSTL or displaytag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, displaytag, rel

I'm using displaytah to display some users information.
In one of the columns I need to have links to users complete details. The problem is that i need to use rel attribute for the link but it seems like displaytag doesn't offer this possibility.

```
<display:column href="foo" class="details" *rel="foo"*>Details</display:column>
```

A possible solution would be to use the JSTL `<c:url>` tag but I can't find any references regarding the rel attribute for this tag either.

Comment: `<c:url>` does not render HTML. It builds a URL and stores it in a variable. If you need a link, use an anchor tag: `<a>`. Yes, it's `*gasp*` _plain old HTML_

Comment: Thank you! That really was unexpectedly simple..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSTL doesn't generate HTML elements. It can be used to generate URLs, though. Just use the following code :

```
<display:column class="details">
    <a href="foo" rel="foo">Details</a>
</display>
```

If the URL must be dynamically composed, which I suppose is true, then use the `<c:url>` tag.

```
<c:url var="detailsUrl" value="foo">
    <c:param name="userId" value="${user.id}"/>
</c:url>
<a href="${detailsUrl}" rel="foo">Details</a>
```